# How to change text color and text font in pptx in python?

Tags: python, colors, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have several hundred presentations. In which I need to change the color and font of the every text and the background color of every slide. How can this be implemented in python?
I tried to understand the pptx module but didn't find suitable videos on Youtube. How to change the previously listed parameters in an existing presentation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

The ideas is to loop over each filename load it, process the changes, then save the new file. It's currently set up to save over the existing file so you may want to either change that or make a backup copy of the current ones. I tested this and it worked as expected.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

file_list = ["file1.pptx", "file2.pptx"]

for file_name in file_list:

    # Open the current file
    ppt = Presentation(file_name)

    # Get all slides in the presentations
    slides = ppt.slides

    # Loop over each slide to process what's inside
    for slide in slides:

        # Access slide background and fill with solid color
        background = slide.background
        fill = background.fill
        fill.solid()
        fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 255)

        
        # Get list of all shapes in slide
        for shape in slide.shapes:

                # If this is a text box then access the text and change the color
                if not shape.has_text_frame:
                    continue
                text_frame = shape.text_frame

                for p in text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in p.runs:
                        font = run.font
                        font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)

    # Save over the existing file
    ppt.save(file_name)
```